# Повторный вопрос про куки?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, cookie

Почему мне неожиданно отобразилось это сообщение?

> Используя наш сайт, вы подтверждаете, что прочитали и поняли [политику о куки](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy), [политику конфиденциальности](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) и [пользовательское соглашение](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public).

Я залогинен в этом браузере давно, ничего необычного не делал и не разлогинивался.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@Taryn♦︎](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/taryn) пишет на en.SO ([Did Stack Overflow update their Cookie or Privacy policy or Terms of Service?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385318)), что сайт должен периодически запрашивать повторное подтверждение у пользователей. Разработчики не знали с каким периодом  выдавать запрос и установили период один год.

Вчера прошел год после выкатывания политики о куки. Соответственно, сайт переспросил у всех, кто дал согласие год назад.

Текст пользовательского соглашения и политик не изменялся, опять же по утверждению @Taryn♦︎.